# Ошибка при написании бота для тг на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Выдает ошибку:
self.register_next_step_handler_by_chat_id(message.chat.id, callback, *args, **kwargs)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'chat'

Вот код:

```
a = None 
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'test') 
def cha_vib(message): 
    global a 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи цифру") 
    bot.register_next_step_handler(a, save_cha) 
    return a 
 
def save_cha(message): 
    global a 
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True) 
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("введи цифру") 
    markup.add(item1) 
    a = message.text 
    return a 
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'test2') 
def wdw(message): 
    save_cha(message) 
    print(a) 
 
 
 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Answer (score 0):

у вас в строке `bot.register_next_step_handler(a, save_cha)` думаю надо вместо `a` передать `message`